# product σ-algebra counter example

Tags: examples-counterexamples

In Real Analysis by Folland,

the product σ-algebra $ \displaystyle \bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M_{\alpha}}  $ on $X$ is defined by the σ-algebra generated by
$ \{ \pi ^{-1} _{\alpha} (E_{\alpha}): E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M_{\alpha}} \}  $

where $ \pi _{\alpha} :  \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} =: X \rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ is a coordinate map.

Prop 1.3: If $A$ is countable, then $ \displaystyle \bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M_{\alpha}}  $ is the σ-algebra generated by $ \{ \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha} : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M_\alpha}    \}  $

I want to find a counter example that if A is uncountable, then the above proposition doesn't hold.. but I'm totally stuck, please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A$ is uncountable and $X$ has more than one point then $x\in X\Rightarrow (x_{\alpha })_{\alpha \in A}\notin \mathscr B(X)^{A}$

Comment: Can you tell me why it is so?
i.e., $ (x_\alpha) _{\alpha \in A} \in \{ \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha : E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M_\alpha}   \}$,
but $ (x_\alpha) _{\alpha \in A} \notin \displaystyle \bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M_\alpha} $ ?

Comment: I guess the idea is this: Singletons are closed in the product space, so they are in $\mathscr B (\prod X)$  but they are not contained in $\otimes\mathscr B(X)$ because every set in the latter is generated by countably many (measurable) rectangles in the product.